# Can anybody tell me a hive query to calculate tot_spend for year range at card number level

Tags: hive

I have a table 'x' with columns report_date, card_no, prod_hierarcy, card_grp, tot_bill(in $)
as shown in below  table with dummy values. I need to write hive query to calculate total spend as column 'y' at card_no level for card_catg wise for all product_hieracy for a year range:  2019- 2020 and for year 2020 and total spend as column 'z'for a year range: 2017 - March,2019

| report_date | card_no | prod_hierarcy | card_grp | tot_bill |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 2437487284 | Gold | Consumer | 900 |
| 2019-02-01 | 3030455445 | platinum | Consumer | 500 |
| 2020-01-01 | 3445322435 | Gold | Business | 300 |
| 2019-01-01 | 2437487284 | Platinum | Consumer | 400 |
| 2020-02-01 | 3030455445 | Bronze | Consumer | 800 |
| 2019-01-01 | 3445322435 | Gold | Business | 700 |
| 2020-05-01 | 2437487284 | Gold | Consumer | 900 |
| 2017-01-01 | 2437487284 | Gold | Consumer | 900 |
| 2019-02-01 | 3445322435 | Gold | Consumer | 100 |
| 2020-05-01 | 2437487284 | Gold | Consumer | 200 |

Comment: can you pls give us sample output? I am not very clear about output but i think you can use `sum (tot_Bill) Over (partition by card_no, prod_hier order by report_date) as x` to calculate column x. You need to apply date filters too on top of the data.

Comment: rephrase the question: I have one mapping table 'mapping_table' for discount rate value on tot_bill by card account number for different 3 product category for group of consumer and Business. I have one transaction table 'txn' for account number having transactions on 1 day of every month (eg. 2019-01-01). Table 'mapping_table' with columns txn_date, card_no, prod_catg, card_grp, tot_bill(in $) . I need to write hive query to calculate total_disc_amount as column x' and 'y' at card_no level for card_catg  for a year

Comment: Need to fetch the discount rate value from mapping table for txn_date falls b/w start_date and end_date and then use in txn table to calculate column tot_dicount_amnt (tot_bill * disc_rate) at account number level

Comment: output look like below,
|report_dt| account_no| prod_catg| prod_hier| tot_disc_bill| |
2019-01-01 |2437487284 | Gold | Consumer | 900 * 2(discount rate)| 
|2019-02-01 |3030455445| Platinum | Consumer | 500 *2|